# Neo4j check id in list

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I want to check whether a relationship is in a list of relationship ids. I tried the following:

```
MATCH (start:Stagepoint),(stop:Stagepoint), path=shortestPath(start-[track:TRACK*]-stop) 
WITH REDUCE(dist = 0, rel in rels(path) | dist + rel.distance) AS distance, path, start.name as start, stop.name as stop, track, [1] as visited 
WHERE distance <= 25 AND distance >= 20 AND NOT ID(track) IN visited  
RETURN start, stop, distance, track ORDER BY distance ASC
```

It get: `` Expected `track` to be a node or relationship, but it was `` ``

I've tried resolving this in multiple ways, but none of them seem to work.

I am using Neo4j 2.1.6 Community Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In variable length paths, the relationship identifier is actually a collection of relationships. So your `track` is a collection of relationships.

Try this:

```
WHERE NONE(t in track WHERE id(t) in visited)
```